# Two Different Laravel Applications using Same Database & Notifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-artisan

I have one application built on say 'mysite.com'. Then after sometime a separate admin panel was created and hosted on admin.mysite.com

Both apps are using same database, but different models and code. Both of the apps have to generate emails, notifications and using ShouldQueue interface to run it in background.

Problem is that if I run `php artisan queue:work` in either app, it fails as soon as it find notification,email generated from other app giving error *Class Not Found*, which is correct as if site app worker processing any notification generated from admin app or the other way.

I think by separating both queues, there could be a way, but not able to get exact start point for this approach.

Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: You could have used [Laravel Subdomain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) instead of creating two different apps working on Same Database...

Comment: @AkshayKhale both projects were done by different teams and I picked up from here. Otherwise I would have considered creating a middleware / guard for admin and protected it with in that. So no need to even have 2 different users tables (users for site users, admin_users for admin panel).

Answer (score 0):

You could enhance your queue code in both apps by catching all the *ClassNotFound* exceptions and push the 'work load' back to the end of the queue. This way both queues would only handle there own 'work loads'.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a way to manage queue by names without any modification in queue handling code.